# How can I lock the window size of a .NET MAUI app?

Tags: .net-maui

I need a solution for locking the window size of a .NET MAUI app. I don't want to allow users to change the app's height and width.(For Windows app)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using `WinUIEx` package for the Windows.

`Step 1`:Install `WinUIEx NuGet package`.

`Step 2`:Update Maui.Program.cs to set your initial window size and position.

```
using Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents;

#if WINDOWS
using WinUIEx;
#endif

namespace MauiApp01;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            }); 

#if WINDOWS
            builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
            {
                events.AddWindows(wndLifeCycleBuilder =>
                {
                    wndLifeCycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated(window =>
                    {
                        //Set size and center on screen using WinUIEx extension method
                        window.CenterOnScreen(1920,1080); 
                    });
                });
            });
#endif
        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

[Reference link.](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/2370#discussioncomment-3027549)

Comment: I allready set the window size , i wanna set those size locked (Not able to change by users)

Comment: It may be a feature request for this scenario, I think you can raise a thread in [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose) or you can follow up with that thread.

Answer (score 0):

To set and lock window size, use similar code from Alexandar, except no need to get WinUIEx, and size it like this (this would size and lock it to 1000x1000:

```
#if WINDOWS
        builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
        {
            events.AddWindows(wndLifeCycleBuilder =>
            {
                wndLifeCycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated(window =>
                {
                    //Set and Lock window size for Windows machine
                    IWindow window1 = new Window() { MaximumWidth = 1000, MaximumHeight = 1000 };
                    window.UpdateMaximumSize(window1);
                });
            });
        });
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can set the size when it is first launched, the minimum size, and the maximum size, like this:

```
#if WINDOWS
        builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
        {
            events.AddWindows(wndLifeCycleBuilder =>
            {
                wndLifeCycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated(window =>
                {
                    //Set size, max size, and min size
                    IWindow window1 = new Window() { 
                        MaximumWidth = 1900, 
                        MaximumHeight = 1000,
                        Width = 1500,
                        Height = 1000,
                        MinimumWidth = 1000,
                        MinimumHeight = 1000
                    };
                    window.UpdateMaximumSize(window1);
                    window.UpdateSize(window1);
                    window.UpdateMinimumSize(window1);
                });
            });
        });
#endif
```

No need for third party extension. The .net core community did such a great job  creating these functionalities